# Add a right button to a nested view in a UINavigation stacking using Storyboards

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar, uistoryboard

Lets say we have a `UIViewController` embedded in a `UINavigationController`, the `UIViewController` segue to another UIViewController.

The second `UIViewController` has the standard left navigation button that "unwinds" to the previous `UIViewController`.

I don't seem to be able to add a righthand button (using a `UIBarButtonItem`) to the navigation bar of the second `UIViewController` via the Storyboard, when I attempt this the button ends up creating a tab bar at the bottom of the `UIViewController` (see below, notice also the left buttons are missing).  Is there some trick I am missing?
[image]

I could embedded the second `UIViewController` in its own `UINavigationController` but then I loss the back button functionality.

I know it is possible to add the button in code so all is not lost if I am attempting something that isint possible.

Comment: If you're using a UIButton, try using a UIBarButtonItem instead.

Comment: I should have been more clear... I am using a UIBarButton

Comment: Try adding a UINavigationItem first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do this in the Storyboard, you need to place a `UINavigationItem` onto your `UIViewController`. Then you can add your `UIBarButtonItem`(s).